# compile a java project with different packages

Tags: java, unix, command-line, compilation, package

I have a java project in eclipse with different packages. How can I compile the project from command line in unix (bash) ? Using plain javac doesnt seem to work. For eg, in eclipse I have

```
src
...server
...client
...shared
```

And the main file that I want to run later is in the server package called server.java

Comment: javac can definitely do it, your IDE is just a wrapper around javac. Check out the `-cp` or `-classpath` arguments to javac to compile in your dependencies. Which class you is your "main" file doesn't really have anything to do with javac, unless you want to specify it as a `main-class` in your `MANIFEST.MF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add all the source paths and dependency .jar files into the compilation call. The easiest way to do this will be to get Eclipse to export an Ant build.xml for the final jar you are trying to compile. This autogenerated ant file is usually pretty messy but gives you an idea of how the project should be built.

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -sourcepath /path/to/src -d /path/to/classes
```